# Can recaptcha be bypassed by sending NULL bytes?

Tags: security, recaptcha

We're running Atomic Secured Linux, and it's been catching posts that are sending NULL bytes in the recaptcha_response_field. The posts in question are definitely spammy, but the only field that gets null bytes is "recaptcha_response_field". In particular, the following is present twice in the POST body:

```
recaptcha_response_field=%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00
```

I'm wondering if this is a known attack against recaptcha, or otherwise a known method of compromising web servers. And if so, what it's intended to do.

Comment: there's probably some stupid/badly implemented recaptcha libraries that are attackable. You'd know if yours was vulnerable, since these spammy responses would be able to reach whatever the captcha's protecting.

Comment: There is spam getting through, but these particular posts were blocked by mod_security before they could get to the server-side recaptcha library, specifically because of the included NULL bytes. So I think whatever method the successful spam is using would have to be different. At this point I'm not 100% certain of that, though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, at least not at recaptcha backend. Google takes security seriously, especially with public services. So  your recaptcha implementation, which communicates with google backend might be attackable, but I still don't think so.

**Just try it. Log each attempt and you'll see if the NULL ones have succeed.**