# Recaptcha not very effective

Tags: php

I've experienced a lot of problems of late with bots signing up to my website.

As a way of getting around this, I added recaptcha to the registration form.

This hasn't stopped the signups, they are still happening as they have of late.

I'm not sure what else I need to provide for you to understand the problem?

I thought recaptcha would prevent this happening!

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Luke.

Comment: captchas can work fine when implemented properly. e.g. are you sure you did it right? Beyond that, how are we supposed to help you? You've provided no code, vague descriptions of the problem, yet expect us to help fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123469/can-recaptcha-be-bypassed-by-sending-null-bytes

Comment: I've read that and understand what it's saying. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: it would be best if you give us a link to your site then we can told you what is wrong with your captcha. Recaptcha is very bad idea if first didn't work then second will not help either.

Comment: a smart spammer would rather look for a simpler loop hole than breaking your `captcha` ... they are definitely other issues with your site ... or you are using one of those badly implemented `recaptcha`

Comment: Ahhh I think that the recaptcha as @MarcB wrote is allowing NULL bytes. I'm changing the technique now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked, which I admit was some time ago, ReCaptcha was broken by spammers or, as @marc-b linked in the comments, the library you're using is broken. Even if it was fixed it is so high-profile that it is very lucrative for spammers to spend time and effort to break it again.

The easiest and most effective captcha is a simple challenge/response, ie: show a picture of something [eg: an apple] and get the user to type that in. Avoid the temptation to just type in a simple math problem, because there are many scripts out there that will figure it out easily.

Comment: I've never used any type of validation such as ReCaptcha before and having used Google to check, it seemed that this was a popular choice. It only took 20 minutes to implement so I'm more than willing to scrap it for a better technique. Are you aware of any script with the images/ word combination you mentioned?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even use a script. One site that I've done just asks "What is the third word in the site's header image?" and another "What company makes the game this site site is about?" and I've never had to change the answers in 5+ years.

Comment: That's what I've gone with, I've asked a question that a spam couldn't possibly know the answer to. Thanks for the reply bud.

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned captcha along time ago in favor of other methods, such as form honeypots. Might want to give it a shot and see if it helps.

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html

Comment: Thanks for this article, a great read.

Comment: No problem! Just remember as developers we're already playing catch-up to the darkside (hacking for profit) markets.

Comment: Do you have any other articles about this that would be an interesting read? I understand the overall dangers but not necessarily the reasons behind it!

Comment: You can find a plethora of articles about alternatives, some are even using games to verify that a form is being filled in by a human. Here's an interesting read on 6 alternatives, most of which I have seen in use on the Internet with increasing adoption: http://www.getelastic.com/6-captcha-alternatives-to-improve-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous services that use humans to solve captchas, with costs around $2 per 1000 captchas correctly solved, so if a spammer thinks their spam is worth more to them than $0.002 then a captcha isnt going to be any use.

These services work by transmitting the image to the worker, and returning the response.
For that reason, a check that does not involve a small graphical puzzel will be much more effective. As suggested by Sammitch, a small list of questions that will NOT make sense out of context (eg what year is it = bad, what color is the letter "B" in our logo = good) is a good option.

Comment: Very interesting, I wasn't aware of such services. Surprising that humans are willing to work for such low amounts of money! I can't imagine there is much profit at those rates. I have gone with the technique of using questions that the spammer can't guess!